# How to get array from FBGraph htmlResponse

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I want to access array of friends for facebook.so for this i am using FBGraph and i get a string

by this line

```
NSString *str=(NSString *)fb_graph_response.htmlResponse;
```

so response is

```
getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  {"data":[{"name":"R.B. Narain","id":"1452788"},{"name":"Jon doe","id":"6564709"}]}
```

now i wanna get array of friends so for this what can i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is JSON response...... you will need JSON parsing..... For this, either you can write your own parser..... or you can use exising one http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

thanks.